# libtool: unrecognized option `-static'

Tags: llvm, libtool

when I install LLVM, error occurred:

```
➜  build make
[  0%] Linking CXX static library ../libLLVMSupport.a
libtool: unrecognized option `-static'
libtool: Try `libtool --help' for more information.
make[2]: *** [lib/libLLVMSupport.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
➜  build which libtool
/usr/local/bin/libtool
```

I have try solve it  fllow this, but failed.

http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2014/04/libtool-unrecognized-option-static.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem this way: changed my PATH in `~/.bash_profile` to `export PATH="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin:$PATH"`, opened a new terminal and ran the installation process again.
The `libtool` in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin` did not complain about the `-static` flag and everything worked well. You can later remove `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin` from your `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I modified your procedure a bit, I just executed make this way :
`PATH="$(xcode-select -p)/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:$PATH" make -j$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)` The Xcode I had installed was Xcode 8.1.